# Aggregating views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i use class based views (which return jsons) with django-rest-framework, and i' d like to create a view which aggregates the results of them (or at least can fetch the responses). Do i' ve any possibility on the server side (so not calling the given urls themselves)?

A small sample can be found here: http://pastebin.com/1bY1CcRA , and basically all i need is a new view which fetches the datas from the *ItemList* and the *ElementList* .

Answer (score 0):

Is that really a good idea? It is better programming design to have distinct models with distinct urls. Perhaps combining the two models into one would be more efficient. If you have to do it this way you are better off not using ModelSerializers.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314173/using-django-rest-framework-to-serialize-custom-data-types-and-return-response?rq=1) for a similar solution.